# Increase header levels of child documents

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I want to create a single PDF document from many `.Rmd` child documents using `pdf_document2()`.

I have a wrapper file `pdf_wrapper.Rmd` that looks as follows

````
---
title: "title"
author: "author"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
  number_sections: true
---

# Header1

```{r child = 'child1.Rmd'}
```
````

With `child1.Rmd` having the following content

```
---
title: "Title2"
output: rmarkdown::html_document
---

## Title 3
```

Now when I render `pdf_wrapper.Rmd`, I get the following:

```
# Header 1
## Title 3
```

I want to end up with

```
# Header 1
## Title 2
### Title 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put all level 2 headers manually in the main document `pdf_wrapper.Rmd`, e.g. `Title2`.
Additionally, I decreased all remaining headers in all child documents by one level using the following bash call:

```
for i in *.Rmd; do
    sed -i '# /## /g' $i
done
```

The main document then looks as follows:

````
---
title: "title"
author: "author"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
  number_sections: true
---

# Header1

## Title2

```{r child = 'child1.Rmd'}
```
````

Initially I though that the `<title>` fields in the YAML metadata of the child documents get processed as level 1 headers but this is not the case.